# Accessing MySQL from Ubuntu Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, heredoc

Ubuntu bash mysql script looks like that

```
mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS  -t -e ' 
CREATE USER $USERNAME@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $MYSQLPASS;
create database $MYSQLDB;
grant usage on *.* to $USERNAME@localhost identified by $MYSQLPASS;
grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to $USERNAME@localhost';
```

Getting error message

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$MYSQLPASS' at line 1
```

In fact $MYSQLPASS is variable with string content. And it's not empty, when I test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash scripts, variable are not replaced by their value when string is enclosed by `'`. Try using `"` instead.

```
mysql -h localhost -u $MYSQLLOGIN -p$MYSQLROOTPASS  -t -e "
CREATE USER '$USERNAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQLPASS';
create database $MYSQLDB;
grant usage on *.* to '$USERNAME'@'localhost' identified by '$MYSQLPASS';
grant all privileges on $MYSQLDB.* to '$USERNAME'@'localhost';"
```

Comment: My bad, you need to enclose password in single quotes.

Comment: Are you sure the user does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your variables in quotes to get valid sql, and your string in interpolating quotes (`"`) to have the variables substituted.